# Empty ListView item is filled with wrong data

Tags: android

I have a TextView and an ImageView in a single ListView item. Both of them or just one of them can be empty.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Problem is when they are empty they don't remain gone and they are filled with data from other ListView items.

How to fix this?

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
            View v = view;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
            }

            String url = results.get(position).get("url");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            if (!url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                if (imageView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(url)
                        .into(imageView);
            }


            String text = results.get(position).get("text");
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            if (!text.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                if (textView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                textView.setText(text);
            }

            return v;
        }
```

Comment: try using ViewHolder

Comment: try this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: You want empty row if url is null?

Answer (score -2):

Because ListView recycles old view items, you need to clear each view as you use it:

```
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        if (!url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            if (imageView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .into(imageView);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        }


       TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if (!text.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            if (textView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            textView.setText(text);
        } else {
            textView.setText("");
        }
```

Comment: is this the correct way to do ? why would not use viewholder pattern for better performance

Comment: yeah viewholder pattern should be used, it depends on the number of items in the list